# Color-code free and busy dates in Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar

Events in Google Calendar can be marked as "free" or "busy". This information can also be provided to collaborators withholding any further event information. For the user creating these events however, this information is not immediately visible from the month, week or day view. The entry has to be opened for editing to inspect it.

I would like to recognize dates I marked as "free" but still keep in my calender immediately. Optimally, I would imagine coloring them more faintly, comparable to how dates in the past are displayed. (I am aware that I could manually assign a different color, but that would be cumbersome and error-prone.) Is it possible to achieve this in the application itself, with a browser extension or by any other means?